# What does "row_id" mean in the flat data of D3.js codebase?

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning D3.js and going through the codebase for a clustered dendrogram visualization. There's the flat data section where the following code is there:

```
{"row_id": "111", "ou_name": "T", "parent": null},
    {"row_id": "112", "ou_name": "R", "parent": "111" },
    {"row_id": "113", "ou_name": "S", "parent": "111" },
    {"row_id": "114", "ou_name": "M", "parent": "112" },
    {"row_id": "115", "ou_name": "O", "parent": "113" },
    {"row_id": "116", "ou_name": "P", "parent": "112" },
    {"row_id": "117", "ou_name": "Q", "parent": "112" },
    {"row_id": "118", "ou_name": "N", "parent": "112" },
    {"row_id": "119", "ou_name": "K", "parent": "114" },
    {"row_id": "120", "ou_name": "A", "parent": "115" },
    {"row_id": "121", "ou_name": "B", "parent": "115" },
    {"row_id": "122", "ou_name": "C", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "123", "ou_name": "D", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "124", "ou_name": "E", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "125", "ou_name": "F", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "126", "ou_name": "G", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "127", "ou_name": "H", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "128", "ou_name": "I", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "129", "ou_name": "J", "parent": "118" },
    {"row_id": "119", "ou_name": "L", "parent": "114" }
```

From the code it's evident that T is the parent for R and S. But what does "row_id" mean here? Is there a particular reason the row_id starts with 111? I changed the row_id for all the nodes i.e. 111 -> 1, 112 -> 2, 113 -> 3 and so on but it didn't work.

Please help me understand this. I tried Google Search but couldn't find any explanation of what row_id is and what it does.

Comment: Did you change the parent property so that it used the updated row_id?

Comment: Yes, of course. I've changed the row_id for every node, and updated the parent for every node accordingly to reflect the changed row_id.

Could you please tell me what row_id means here and why does it have to start with only 111?

Comment: It shouldn't have to start with any number, nor have any particular name for an id property or parent property. D3 does not use any specific property names here nor does it expect a format other than a string or number for the id to be used in the hierarchy. Can you share the example you are working with? If it is this [one](https://jsfiddle.net/4ehpgxtn/), I've changed the first IDs to "A" and "B" and it runs as before.

Comment: Also in the linked example you can see that 'row_id' and 'parent' are arbitrary, with d3.stratify() being provided these names here: `.id( function(d) { return    d.row_id; }).parentId( function(d) { return d.parent; })`. Some property containing the node id is required, `row_id` here, and a property that identifies the parent node is required, `parent` in this example. The info passed to d3.stratify must include at least these two properties in order to create the hierarchy.